# Apps script: filter out empty elements from array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[image]

I have the following function:

```
  var rows = sheet2Json(sheet);

  var emails = rows.filter(function (el) { //ONLY CHECKED ROWS.
         return el != "";
    })
               .map(function (row) { //ONLY CHECKED ROWS.
      return row['EMAIL'];
    });  



  Logger.log(emails)
  return (emails);
}
```

rows produces the sheet in an array of objects that looks like:

```
[{ EMAIL=xxx,  TEMPLATE=CONSULT, Index=Thu Jan 24 16:26:02 GMT-05:00 2019 }
...
]
```

I want an array of all the emails filtering out the empty rows. With the code above I'm getting:

```
[ K@DF.COM, K@DF.COM,  , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]
```

How can I get rid of the empty rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the `EMAIL` property first, then filter the entries which are empty or undefined:

```js
var rows = [
  { EMAIL: 'a@b.com', prop: 'bla' },
  { EMAIL: '', prop: 'bla' },
  { EMAIL: undefined },
  { EMAIL: 'd@b.com', prop: 'bla' },
  { },
  undefined
];

var emails = rows
  .map(function (row) { return row && row.EMAIL; })
  .filter(Boolean);

console.log(emails);
```

The reason it's not working the other way is that you need to filter out the empty EMAIL fields, but you are filtering rows by comparing them to an empty string. An empty row (`{}`) will not pass your filter test.

To make it work the other way, you need to filter the rows based on their EMAIL property first, then map:

```js
var rows = [
  { EMAIL: 'a@b.com', prop: 'bla' },
  { EMAIL: '', prop: 'bla' },
  { EMAIL: undefined },
  { EMAIL: 'd@b.com', prop: 'bla' },
  { },
  undefined
];

var emails = rows
  .filter(function (row) { return row && row.EMAIL; })
  .map(function (row) { return row.EMAIL; });

console.log(emails);
```

Comment: Apps Script is basically JS 1.6. No includes, no let, no iterators, no arrow syntax. It does have map, filter, reduce, some, and every support.

Comment: @user61629, I updated the answer and added more explanations

Comment: regarding "return row && row.EMAIL;" - I'm assuming that means if row exists return row.Email ?

Comment: @user61629, Yes you are right, if row is falsy, the right most expression is not evaulated and undefined is returned

Answer (score 2):

- You want to retrieve the values of `EMAIL` from the object like `[{ EMAIL=xxx,  TEMPLATE=CONSULT, Index=Thu Jan 24 16:26:02 GMT-05:00 2019 }...]` using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, How about this modification? In this modification, I used `reduce()`. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

```
var emails = rows.reduce(function (ar, row) {
  row['EMAIL'] && ar.push(row['EMAIL']);
  return ar;
}, []);
```

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Thank you! its a great example!

Comment: regarding "row['EMAIL'] && ar.push(row['EMAIL']" - does this mean "if email exists push it to the accumulator array" ?

Comment: @user61629 Yes. That's right. Also, By putting ``row['EMAIL']`` before ``ar.push(row['EMAIL'])``, at first, ``row['EMAIL']`` is compared.